# java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Invalid number format for port number

Tags: java, jdbc, ojdbc

```
package jdbcconnection;

import java.sql.*;

public class Jdbc2{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

        //Resgister the driver through 

         Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
         System.out.println("registered driver successfully");
         //Create the connection and assign to connection reference
         Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:CUSTDB", "scott", "tiger");
         System.out.println("connection successsfully");
         //create a statement through connection reference and assign to statement reference
         Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
         System.out.println("statement object created successfully");
         //call the executequery method through statement reference and pass the query as argument.
         ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");

         System.out.println("query is executed");

         while(rs.next()){
             int i=rs.getInt(1);
             String str=rs.getString(2);
             String str1=rs.getString(3);
             int i1=rs.getInt(4);
             System.out.println(i+"\t"+str+"\t"+str1+"\t"+i1);    
         }
    }
}
```

error--

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Invalid number format for port number
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:439)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at jdbcconnection.Jdbc2.main(Jdbc2.java:13)
```

Comment: We would love to help, but you need to actually format a question here.  Just copy pasting code is not going to get any answers and just down voted into oblivion.  We don't know what the problem is (what is breaking), or ANY information about the problem.  We have code, some text error, and nothing else to go on.  Most people will need a LOT more before they even try and attempt to help/solve this issue... whatever it is.

Answer (score 5):

What I've noticed is specifying SID instead of Service Name with a `/` does not work. So the following is not correct:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@my.host.com:1521/DB_SID
```

It's going to throw `listener doesn't know of service ...` error. When you use SID, you should put a colon instead of a slash.

And this one will complain about the invalid port number format

```
jdbc:oracle:thin://@my.host.com:1521:DB_SID
```

Did you notice the double slashes before the `@` sign? Just remove them and everything will be ok.

Comment: I get `Invalid URL: r2dbc:oracle:thin:@HOST:PORT:SID` PS: as you can see, I'm using r2dbc

Answer (score 2):

Your URL is incorrect.

It should be

```
getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:portnum:CUSTDB", "scott", "tiger");
```

Example:

```
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "scott", "tiger"
```

where xe is the database name.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the stack trace: "Invalid number format for port number"
You should put a valid port number instead of `CUSTDB`

Answer (score 0):

```
while(rs.next()){
             int i=rs.getInt(1);
             String str=rs.getString(2);
             String str1=rs.getString(3);
             int i1=rs.getInt(4);
             System.out.println(i+"\t"+str+"\t"+str1+"\t"+i1);
```

This is incorrect too! You need to use field names to get values instead of numbers like 1,2,3 etc. And yeah, do check with your port number to get around with the port exception!
Check this for a demo on JDBC: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm

And yeah, please be more informative about your work and frame a proper question instead of just posting the Error stack!

Comment: This is perfectly valid.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(int)